# SQL Server : how to normalize table column with index

Tags: sql-server

I need to parse this table:

```
╔══════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║ Year ║ Cost_Mon1 ║ Cost_Mon2 ║ Cost_Mon3 ║
╠══════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ 2022 ║      1176 ║      3970 ║       540 ║
║ 2023 ║       540 ║       540 ║      3716 ║
╚══════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

To this format with efficient way (better performance)

```
╔══════╦═══════╦══════╗
║ Year ║ Month ║ Cost ║
╠══════╬═══════╬══════╣
║ 2022 ║     1 ║ 1176 ║
║ 2022 ║     2 ║ 3970 ║
║ 2022 ║     3 ║  540 ║
║ 2023 ║     1 ║  540 ║
║ 2023 ║     2 ║  540 ║
║ 2023 ║     3 ║ 3716 ║
╚══════╩═══════╩══════╝
```

Comment: I would suggest to compare the execution plans between union all and cross join.

Comment: if this is actually what your data looks like, and your concern is query performance, I'd suggest having an agent job fire every month to populate a different table that you query, rather than trying to query a table that doesn't suite your needs.

Comment: i have pasted the different execution plans

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a union approach:

```sql
SELECT Year, 1 AS Month, Cost_Mon1 AS Cost FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT Year, 2, Cost_Mon2 FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT Year, 3, Cost_Mon3 FROM yourTable
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

Comment: OPs question is focused on performance and this answer is the less performant one.

Comment: @jmvcollaborator If you check the source code for `UNPIVOT`, I believe it is using a union under the hood.  Yes, your `CROSS APPLY` solution might outperform my answer.  But the OP's performance concern is not about the _answer_ so much, but rather moving away from the original unnormalized table.  The amount of time needed to get to the correct table structure is not the main focus of the question IIUC.

Answer (score 2):

Since the performance is a need on your question i would consider two of the best performant approaches:

1. Unpivot

It only allows a single column to be unpivoted, it does not meet your needs.

2. Cross join (values)

It allows multiple columns, here is the sql and [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3959a/18):

> SELECT t.*
> FROM YearCost
> CROSS APPLY (
> VALUES
> (Year, 1,Cost_Mon1)
> , (Year, 2,Cost_Mon2)
> , (Year, 3,Cost_Mon3))
> t(Year, Cost,Month)

Other approaches less performant are:
Union all,dynamic Unpivot with XML (yeah you can perform a trick)

> Conclusion:
>
> When we need to carry out a simple conversion of columns into rows in
> SQL Server, it is better to use UNPIVOT or VALUES structures.
>
> If, after the conversion, the received data rows should be used for
> aggregation or sorting, then we had better use the VALUES structure,
> which, in most cases, results in more efficient execution plans.

[Source](https://blog.devart.com/is-unpivot-the-best-way-for-converting-columns-into-rows.html)

**UPDATE**: Execution plans (based on the created fiddle)

1. Cross join

No multiple scans per subquery since there are no subqueries here.

[image]

2. Union all

There is multiple data reading. This happens because UNION ALL will scan the rows once for every subquery, which considerably decreases the efficiency of the query execution.
[image]

Comment: it really gave me another way thinking

Comment: If I read the OP correctly, the goal is to get to the new table structure because that structure is more performant than the starting point.  This, rather than the performance of the answers, is the focus of the question.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen your approach works as a charm, lets check with OP what suits better, thanks !